# Launch an oversize terminal window from a script

Tags: resize, gnome, csh, rhel, window-resize

I'm using gnome in RHEL 6.4 and I've created a desktop launcher to open a terminal window to present data from a flatfile to a user (actually the launcher opens a terminal window and executes a script file, which will present the data to the users).  The data is about 650 characters wide.

I've tried two concepts that I could think of, but in both cases have been limited by (presumably) the window manager itself:

xterm -geometry 650x25 -e /path/to/my/script.sh &

and resize -s 25 650 from within the /path/to/my/script.sh

Both will make the xterm the size of the actual desktop (with my current resolution, approximately only about 300 characters wide).
This causes a problem when presenting the data in the script.sh due to word wrapping.

My current workaround is to prompt the user to resize the window manually before presenting the data to them...

Is there a way to open up the terminal window to the specified size, regardless of the current size of the gnome window?  Or better yet, is there a way to use the resize the window after launch (ala resize -s ); this would be preferred as there are two types of files to present to the user.  One is only 450 characters wide, and the other is 650.  I would love to be able to start up at 450, and if the longer file is selected, change the window to 650.

(Of Note, I recall the Solaris Java Desktop had this behavior by default; but this behavior is typically undesirable other than in the instance described above; therefore I do not want to change the default behavior of the window manager for all windows; just on the terminal window launched with the desktop launcher!)

Appreciate any ideas!

Thanks,

KSL.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I guess this wasn't for nothing; I've just been awarded a Tumbleweed badge for getting no responses.